# what is the size of this range 0x 0000 0000 - 0x 0001 BFFF?

Tags: memory-management, memory-address

Can you please share what is the size of the address range,
0x 0000 0000 - 0x 0001 BFFF.

I Can use a calculator to find, I need a method to calculate any range.
Ex. 0x 0020 CD00 - 0x 002C  BCFF,

How can i know the size of this address range in decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x0001BFFF` or `114687` bytes. You could obtain size by substracting low address from high address of the range.

Comment: obtaining the size is fine, wanted to know how to express the value 0x1BFFF in decimal directly without using the calculator.

0x 0020 CD00 - 0x 002C BCFF => size is BEFFF,
But please share the size in decimal without using calculator

Comment: 0x1BFFF = 1*16^4 + 11*16^3 + 15*16^2 + 15*16^1 + 15*16^0 = 114687

Comment: thanks,
can you please share the other way round too,i.e,
given 8Mb of data to be mapped at address 0x 002C BCFF,
How to know the final address of the range.

Comment: 8MB = 8*2^20 = 8*16^5 = 0x800000. 0x002CBCFF + 0x00800000 =  0x00ACBCFF